# Alert Controller Does not Appear Error! Swift-Project

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alert, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to change (edit) the user email in an iOS application using swift and firebase.
In changing email function I added some errors and alert for each error.

When I simulated, and tested the errors, for example, I tried to enter invalid email, the error works correctly!
But the alert does not appear, and it gives me this error as in the picture below.
[image]

Here's the code:

```
    if EmailAddressTF.text=="" || PasswordTF.text=="" || BusinessNameTF.text==""
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Make sure to fill in all required textfields", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
    }

    else {

        if RepasswordTF.text != PasswordTF.text
        {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"You Entered Different Passwords", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
        }

        else {

            let ref = Firebase(url: "https://businesswallet.firebaseio.com/")

            let mainpass = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("password") as? String
            let mainEmail = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Email") as? String


            let isEqu = (mainEmail == self.EmailAddressTF.text)
            if(isEqu == true)
            {   }
            else
            {
                ref.changeEmailForUser(mainEmail, password: mainpass, toNewEmail: self.EmailAddressTF.text, withCompletionBlock: { error in

                    if error != nil {

                        if let errorCode = FAuthenticationError(rawValue: error.code) {

                            switch (errorCode) {
                            case .EmailTaken:
                                print("Email taken")
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Sorry,Email taken", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                                self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true){}

                            case .InvalidEmail:
                                print("invalid email")
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"invalid email", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                               self.presentViewController(alert, animated:true){}


                            case .NetworkError:
                                print("Network Error")
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Network error, check your connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}

                            default:
                                print("Unknown Error")
                                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"Unknown Error", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })
                                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                            }
                        }





                    } else {

                        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(self.EmailAddressTF.text, forKey: "Email")
                        print("Email changed successfully")

                    }

                })

            } //Big Else
```

And how can I fix this?

Comment: it means you're presenting that alert on the wrong viewController or view.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to present the alert controller from a view controller that is not currently presented.

Comment: But the view controller is currently presented!! I did not get it!! What does that mean?

Comment: you present a view controller over another controller but you don't keep a reference to it so it gets only retained by the storyboard and then when you go to present another modal (aka the alert) the other view is no longer in the storyboard and gets deallocated for having no references and since the controller that the alert was going to present on is now nil it fails. You also don't display the alert on the main thread.

Comment: @A'sa Dickens, What should I do now to solve this?

Comment: IDK what your set up is like, but i'm going to say is `vc1` has a property for `vc2` and then in vc1 when you touch the button to present vc2 you say `self.vc2Property = vc2` and then you say `self.presentController(vc2, animated: yesPlease)`

Comment: If what you said is true, what do you think should I do?

Comment: Is there anyone else know how can I solve this? Please? :(

Answer (score 0):

This is obj-c code, but you can easily convert it to swift.

```
- (void)throwAlert
{
    UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController
                                    alertControllerWithTitle:@"myTitle"
                                    message:@"myMessage"
                                    preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction *defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (window.rootViewController.presentedViewController != nil)
        {
            [window.rootViewController.presentedViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [window.rootViewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    });
```

}

swift:

```
func throwAlert()
    {
        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Oops!", message:"You Entered Different Passwords", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { _ in })

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            if window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController != nil
            {
                window.rootViewController?.presentedViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
            }
            else
            {
                window.rootViewController!.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: The compiler forced me to add an exclamation mark before the second dot! When tested it in the simulator, it gave me this error: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: yes...you need exclamation mark there...that's correct. But your presented controller in nil, that's why the crash happens. Can you post the code for your class where you're trying to call this alert?

Comment: Oh, please no, I cannot read objective-C at all. Could you give it to me in swift please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109280/discussion-between-eugene-zhenya-gordin-and-mariah).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109337/discussion-between-mariah-and-eugene-zhenya-gordin).

Answer (score 0):

Try to present the alert within the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: head, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
print("you have pressed OK button");
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: false, completion:nil)
}
```

Comment: Where should add this exactly?

Comment: On every place that you want to present the alert. In your case, on every `case`

Comment: I tried it, it gave me the same error in the console!

Answer (score 0):

For adding alert controller add this global method in any of your helper class.

```
func popAlertMessageController(VC:(UIViewController), title:(String), message:(String)) {
    let alertController:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    let ok:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (action) -> Void in
        alertController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    alertController.addAction(ok)
    VC.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And you can call this method from anywhere you require for an alert as follows:

```
popAlertMessageController(self, title: "Alert", message: "Your message")
```